# Strange script behaviour when shebang references different shell

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh, shebang

I've recently switched to the ksh93 shell. I did this by adding the following two lines to my .profile file

```
export SHELL=/usr/local/bin/ksh93
exec $SHELL
```

Since I did that some simple scripts have started misbehaving in a way I don't understand. I narrowed it down to the following simple script called say `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo $0 $1
```

If I type the command `test.sh fred` I would expect to see the same output `test.sh fred`. Instead I see `test.sh noglob`. If I remove the shebang or if I change it to read `#!/usr/local/bin/ksh93` then the script works as expected.

Can anyone explain what's going on, or what to do about it? I'm stumped.

I'm using Solaris 5.9 if it makes any difference.

Comment: What's in `/bin/ksh`?  Presumably a shell script which replaces the value of `$1` somehow, perhaps out of carelessness.

Comment: @tripleee /bin/ksh is the korn shell (the one I was using before I switched to ksh93)

Comment: What happens if you run `/bin/ksh -x -c 'echo "$0" "$1"'`?

Comment: It dumps out a whole load of commands (my .profile etc) but at the end it still says `/bin/ksh noglob`

Comment: Um, those loads of commands would probably be worthy of further study.

Comment: I think triplee is on the right path. Check what's in /bin/ksh by tracking down what it links to and checking the content of it. It's probably a wrapper to ksh. Also --version giving you no output indicates it's a wrapper.

Comment: So just to confirm, what's the output of `file /bin/ksh` and `ls -l /bin/ksh`?

Comment: On Solaris, `/bin/ksh` is (by default) the actual executable for the `ksh`.  The non-support of `--version` simply indicates that it is a real (and probably old) Korn shell.

Comment: It sounds as though something in the `ksh` start up files is clobbering the options passed in to the script, maybe with `set -- noglob` but more probably with a more subtle mechanism (but `set` probably figures).  Look hard at all the commands before the `echo`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right. My .kshrc contained the following line alias rs 'set noglob; eval `resize`'; rs. I didn't realise I was following instructions for the C shell. If you or tripleee want to right up your comments I'll accept as an answer.

Comment: Solaris 2.x through Solaris 10 have always shipped with the ksh88 from the original SVR4, plus some sun-specific bugs and enhancements (e.g., handling of $ENV and internationalisation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice from the comments that your `.kshrc` has a `set noglob`.  The `set` command with no options will set the command-line parameters, which is why `$1` is "noglob", it should be `set -o noglob`.

By the way, setting `noglob` is weird, are you sure you want that?

I suspect (as others have mentioned) that `/bin/ksh` is Korn shell 88.
There is an important difference between ksh88 and ksh93 with regards to `.kshrc`.  On ksh88 `.kshrc` is executed for every korn shell process, even non-interactive ones (scripts).  In ksh93 `.kshrc` is *not* executed for shell scripts, only for interactive login shells.

When you do `exec $SHELL` that is not a login shell, it is better to change your entry in `/etc/passwd`.  By the way, using variable `SHELL` is a bad idea, since that is set by the login shell.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm aware of most of the issues you raised. Unfortunately it's not practical for me to change /etc/passwd, too much bureaucracy involved. The set noglob was because I was following these instructions http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/resize.1.asp without realising they are for the C shell. I've fixed that now.

Comment: Somewhere halfway through Solaris 10, `ksh88sun` behaviour with regard to `$ENV` was fixed in an update/patch.  Until then it was quite common to have scripts start with `#!/bin/ksh -p` to prevent `$ENV` from being used in a script.  *(The -p option was never more than a workaround)*

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an alias on ksh in your system with noglob set as an option, or noglob is being passed as a default parameter by default in your old shell. You should also check what ksh you're really calling (check if there's a link to another shell in from /bin/ksh). ksh --version should give some insight as well.

As a last point, instead of calling the shell directly i'd recommend to use

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ksh
```

Comment: I have no alias for ksh, nor is /bin/ksh a link to anything. `ksh -version` just gives an error `-version: bad option(s)`. I don't understand the bit about default arguments. Using `#!/usr/bin/env ksh` makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry it's ksh --version. The #!/usr/bin/env PROGRAM is a general rule you should follow since it makes your scripts (little more) independent of the system. If you try ksh -o you'll see all the ksh shells options (glob/noglob is one of them). The version number should give you more insight into this odd behavior.

Comment: `ksh --version` produces no output, `ksh -o` says noglob off.

Comment: `ksh --version` is unsupported with ksh88, which is the one used with Solaris, `--version` is a ksh93 feature. One workaround would be `strings /bin/ksh | grep Version`. @count0, please don't suggest to link /bin/ksh to something else. ksh is part of core Solaris. Replacing it might break existing scripts and make the system unsupported.

Comment: I've removed the suggestion. Didn't think of solaris specific system scripts which would rely on ksh88. Most linux distros link important system tools to /etc/defaults to allow customization of that behavior. I've never run into a ksh without --version support (on a multitude of systems), which is a surprising fact after all. On the other hand the 88 version is 24 years old by now, being quite a fossil.